# Messed up my linux installation

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I am totally new to Linux and installed a Peppermint Partition on my HD. Then I tried to install from Peppermint a live USB, but ended up mounting the image on the hard drive.

Now I have this installation listed among Devices. I have run "mount" and got this line among others:

> /dev/sdb on /media/jack/Prova Live type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)

How can I delete it? If I run Gparted it shows there is unallocated space only on sdb, but if I click on the icon of the usb installation that I am trying to remove on Devices, a folder opens with directories in it.

I have tried unmount dev/sdb and reboot but the icon and the folder is still there...if I run mount I don't see it at first, but if I click on it from the device menu and then run mount it shows up in the list...
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the Peppermint installer, and what did it do? lsblk & blkid & gparted should help identify what's what. sdb looks like the iso on a dvd or usb, it's not your hard drive is it, with no partitions?

Comment: I used "dd" to mount the image!

Comment: Good 'ol Data Destroyer, it doesn't really "mount" things, reads & writes just about anything, like turn a HD into a dvd. Doesn't Peppermint have an installer when it runs live? Boot from a usb/dvd and  just install to the hard drive... may need new MBR/GPT now though

Comment: I realize now I made an error in the question, I am not trying to install Peppermint, it is already installed on my HD. What I have tried was install it on a USB to make it live and bootable, but accidentally set the target for the installation on the HDD instead than the USB, and now I cannot remove it.

Comment: Did you have anything on that drive that you care at all about?

Comment: Nothing, I can erase it all...

Comment: Problem is that when I run gparted it shows only unallocated space on that drive, so I don't know how to delete!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/dev/sdb` is the drive you're trying to "un-iso", it would appear that you've overwritten sdb's old MBR/GPT partition table.

Now `gparted` may not see any partitions and says it's all unallocated space (that's what mine does when I setup an .iso file as a loop device, and have gparted examine the loop device).

So, start up `gparted` and examine `/dev/sdb`, tell it to **Create a new Partition Table** (MBR/GPT/etc) by:

- Going to the menu *Device* -> *Create Partition Table* and
- write a new partition table.

The "*msdos*" type is the old MBR, or "*gpt*" is the new GPT partition table, use whichever you prefer or google for advice.

After that, make a new partition (or a few, whatever you want).

---

If you just want to make a bootable live USB, you can use a program like Unetbootin, or Universal USB Installer.

Or I prefer a multiboot USB (even if there's only one .iso to boot) since it doesn't overwrite the whole drive's partition table like plain `dd` does, and you can use a filesystem like ext3/4 or something more reliable than FAT (FAT USB's tend to erase all their filenames somewhat regularly for me somehow, never a problem on the same USB with ext3).

Instructions can be found in [this other A of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572004/universal-usb-installer-cant-detect-usb/572023#572023) and they're basically:

> [As] described [here on Arch's Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) or [here on
>   pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/), for many distros you just copy the ISO file
>   onto the usb and edit grub.cfg. Cliff notes instructions are:
>
> 1. Mount the usb
> 2. Install grub grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdx (replacing x with your actual USB device & /mnt/usb with mounted dir)
> 3. Put demo grub.cfg ( http://pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg ) in
>      /mnt/USB/boot/grub and edit to match your iso's
>
> Or see the [Ubuntu help on creating & installing from bootable
>   USB's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), can the Ubuntu tool Startup Disk Creator, Unetbootin, or
>   plain `dd`.

And I *think* you could even make it persistent by adding another partition on the USB just named "casper-rw", similar to [these instructions on pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/) , but I haven't tested it with a multiboot usb